# Oracle Column Value Modification

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql

I am trying to fix an issue where some of the items in my table **Documents** Have a typo in one of the columns

Where it should read **Important: Please Read** it instead reads **ImportantPlease Read**

I'm using not to good with Oracle, but how would I essentially do this

```
Update Documents Set Overview = "Imporantant: Please Read " + 
Overview.SubStr(19, Overview.Length) Where Overview Like 'ImportantPlease Read%'
```

Now I know this is nowhere near Oracle Syntax but I was wondering if you could help me fill in the gaps

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if you need further explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want

```
UPDATE documents
   SET overview = 'Important: Please Read ' || substr( overview, 19 )
 WHERE overview LIKE 'ImportantPlease Read%'
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Documents
SET Overview = REPLACE(Overview, 'ImportantPlease', 'Important: Please')
WHERE Overview LIKE 'ImportantPlease%';
```